# Angular App Not Working When Moving to Python Flask

Tags: python, angular, flask, iis

Not sure what information to give so will do as much as I can.

Currently have an Angular app sitting on IIS and using Classic ASP. All works fine. There is a dropdown which fetches some JSON that then populates a table.

Now, I have moved this over to Flask. When I select a dropdown and the table gets populated, I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'clientWidth')
```

The code is below

```
app.directive('widthSetter', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            $timeout(function () {
                var el = attr.widthSetter + '_top'
                element.css({ 'min-width': document.getElementById(el).clientWidth + 'px' }) // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

My knowledge with Angular is severely limited. However, I can't see what has happened from Classic ASP to Flask to have made this happen.

There are no JS/Python errors when the app loads initially. Just when this one specific action happens.

The code snippet above looks like it tries to set the width of table cols/headers. When I inspect the code, I can see the below

```
<th id="id_top" ng-repeat="heading in dimensionDataHeading" ng-bind="heading | underscores" ng-if="$index < dimensionDataHeading.length-3" class="ng-binding ng-scope">id</th>
```

Has anyone got any suggestions? The table gets populated but the widths aren't set properly, presuming due to the above.

If I add

```
console.log(attr.widthSetter);
```

I get a list such as:

- id
- start_date
- end_date
- etc

Then I get an error for each one that was successfully logged to the console. When I did a console.log in the Classic ASP application, I get the same first list but (obviously) instead of a second list of errors, I got a second list identical to the first

Thanks,

PS

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, you need more detailed error information to analyze and solve the problem, you can try to check the console or event viewer.

Comment: The error in the console is given alongside the code that is producing the error.

Comment: That's not [Angular](https://angular.io). It's [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org). These are two different frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python flask uses Jinja templates that use `{{}}` which is what AngularJS also uses so doing `{{ '{{ variable_name }}' }}` in the relevant places solved my issues